# Sandbox parameters for a larger testnet

Tags: sandbox, performance, scalability, parameter

I am currently doing some measurements of Tezos' performance, running on Carthagenet. For this purpose, I deploy private testnets of variable size with the following sandbox parameters:

`{
    "preserved_cycles": 2,
    "blocks_per_cycle": 8,
    "blocks_per_commitment": 4,
    "blocks_per_roll_snapshot": 4,
    "blocks_per_voting_period": 4,
    "time_between_blocks": ["10", "5"],
    "endorsers_per_block": 2,
    "hard_gas_limit_per_operation": "1040000",
    "hard_gas_limit_per_block": "10400000",
    "proof_of_work_threshold": "-1",
    "tokens_per_roll": "8000000000",
    "michelson_maximum_type_size": 1000,
    "seed_nonce_revelation_tip": "125000",
    "origination_size": 0,
    "block_security_deposit": "512000000",
    "endorsement_security_deposit": "64000000",
    "baking_reward_per_endorsement": ["1250000", "187500"],
    "endorsement_reward": ["1250000", "833333"],
    "cost_per_byte": "1000",
    "hard_storage_limit_per_operation": "60000",
    "test_chain_duration": "1966080",
    "quorum_min": 2000,
    "quorum_max": 7000,
    "min_proposal_quorum": 500,
    "initial_endorsers": 1,
    "delay_per_missing_endorsement": "1"
  }`

On every node, I also run a baker, an endorser and an accuser. Moreover, all nodes have the same stake and therefore the same probability to be elected as baker in a certain period.

I was generally happy that Tezos run highly stable and I managed to get a throughput of > 500 tx/s in a 16 and 32 node network with 2 CPUs each. However, for 64 nodes things changed dramatically, and I only managed to get about 3 tx/s. I have already tried to increase the `time_between_blocks` parameter to ["20", "10"] to account for a larger network size and therefore longer block propagation. I guess that I have to adapt other parameters as well for larger network sizes. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just a remark: as the end of cycle is quite computationally heavy, an idea would be to increase the number of blocks per cycle, to say 256 blocks. It then makes sense to increase `blocks_per_commitment` and `blocks_per_roll_snapshot` accordingly.